# A problem of a function, a composite function and inverse function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions such that $f(x) = x^3+3x+2$, $g(f(x))=x$ and $h(g(g(x)))=x$, $\forall$ $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then

A) $g'(2) =\frac{1}{15}$

B) $h'(1)=666$

C) $h(0)=16$

D) $h(g(3)) = 36$

*Note: The answer is B,C.*

Comment: This question is from the JEE Advanced 2016 in the Multiple-Correct section of Math.

Comment: Hint: $g$ and $f$ are inverses (and $f$ is one-to-one for a reason)

Comment: I noticed that so I was able tell that A isn't correct, but I'm not sure about how to approach the other options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $g(x)=f^{-1}(x) \implies g^{-1}(x)=f(x)$, $f(g(x))=x$. Next $$h(g(g(x)))=x \implies h^{-1}(x)=g(g(x)) \implies h(x)= g^{-1}(g^{-1}(x))=f(f(x)).$$
Eventually, as $f(x)=x^3+3x+2$, we get $$h(x)=f(x^3+3x+2)=(x^3+3x+2)^3+3(x^3+3x+2)+2$$
So from here it follows that $h(0)=16$, and $h(g(3))=f(f(g(3))=f(3)=38,$ $h'(1)=666, g'(3)=\frac{1}{3}$
So options (B) and (C) are correct.